# WordPress theme footer wont load images

Tags: php, css, wordpress, lan

hi I am fairly new to WordPress and maybe I don't know how thing work in this CMS but I cant figure out why I cant do even smallest thing. I forked WordPress repository in git hub and started working.

I changed footer but it dose not load table background image, I tried to change it in table properties and css but neither helped. I am using dreamweather so there shouldn't be problems with path specification.

another strange thing is that I use wamp server on my eee that is connected to a lan and I use my desktop to connect to my eee.  a site that has no cms (the other project) loads like it should but my WordPress site load without no images and css, are these 2 thing connected in some way and how can I fix them?

here is a link to my WordPress repository on GitHub:

https://github.com/qazedx/WordPress/tree/muse_wordpress

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right, that you are talking about this `background="images/Sand1.jpg"`?

You need to tell wordpress to look inside your theme directory

```
background="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Sand1.jpg"
```

Since WordPress then looks for your image like this `www.example.com/images/Sand1.jpg`.

In CSS, only there you can write relative URLs to images, ...

btw: why do you have `<!doctype...` in your footer?